# Android Emulator has issues with File I/O operations

Tags: android, emulation

I have created an app with android studio. it has some text files which will copy on device. **app running normal on real device but on emulator it was fail with message *i/o* error**. 
all other function are running normal on both.

Comment: post the error message

Answer (score 0):

I've found a solution. The emulator has Android – Marshmallow.

1. Select the app icon and move to app info.
2. Select permissions.
3. On storage allow it by moving the button to the right side.

Now it's running OK.